# Label.so is missing

Tags: plymouth

After upgrading packages, the error appeared:

> W: plymouth: The plugin label.so is missing, the selected theme might not work as expected. W: plymouth: You might want to install the plymouth-themes and plymouth-label package to fix this.

what's that and How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Before it was a bug that was fixed in the package `plymouth - 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1`

First Do as the error suggests, install the packages `plymouth-themes` and `plymouth-label`

`sudo apt-get install plymouth-themes plymouth-label`

If that doesn't fix,then install a full `plymouth` package

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth
```

Then update/clean old  kernel

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```